# PascalScript: how to correctly interpret Unit Importer output?

Tags: delphi, pascalscript

I'm giving a try to PascalScript, due to its features which could be very interesting in one of the programs I am developing.

Then, after following the awesome Lawrence Barsanti's introduction to PascalScript [here](http://lawrencebarsanti.wordpress.com/2009/11/28/introduction-to-pascal-script/), I came to have a look at the RemObjects Unit Importer.

Question is: I understood Lawrence's tutorial is focused on how to use PS without Unit Importer, but since I have rich and sometimes complex forms to work with, having a tool that already does the unit contents mapping could be a bliss.

Just, I can't figure out how to use Unit Importer output: is it a unit file to import into the project? What do I need to do to correctly use it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit importer parses the `interface` section of a unit and generates an *import unit* for use by Pascal Script. It makes the Delphi code from the imported unit accessible to the Pascal Script interpreter. Include *both* units (the original and the generated one) in your project.

Instead of manually typing all the `AddDelphiFunction` calls to add your functions to Pascal Script, the importer *generates code* to call those functions for you. If you have `USEIMPORTER` defined in your project, then the import unit will automatically register the imported types, functions, and constants with the interpreter. Otherwise, you'll have to call the `SIRegister_X` function yourself when you have your own interpreter class ready.

Comment: Thank you, it is clear now. Only, I tried to $Define USEIMPORTER in my .dpr, but it seems I still can't have types, functions and constants automatically registered. Am I missing something?

Comment: Things defined in one file do not apply to other files. To have something apply to the entire project, define it in the project options.